# Populating WTForm FormField in a Flask view when object doesn't match form field names

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form setup like so:

```
class AddressForm(FlaskForm):
  line1 = StringField()
  city = StringField()
  postcode = StringField()

class PlaceForm(FlaskForm):
  name = StringField()
  address = FormField(AddressForm)
```

And then I have a Flask view something like this:

```
@bp.route("/places/<ident>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_place(ident):
  place = api.get_place(ident)

  form = PlaceForm(obj=place)
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    # do stuff with the form data

  return render_template('place/edit.html', form=form)
```

The `api.get_place(ident)` returns data that doesn't match the shape of the field names in my `Form` classes, so my forms are always empty when rendered in the browser. For example, the response from the API might look like this:

```
{
  "place": {
    "place_name": "Foobar",
    "address": {
      "address1": "500 5th St",
      "locality": "San Francisco",
      "post_code": "90210"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I customize the code populates the `PlaceForm` with data when passing in `obj`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell if this is actually the pattern you want. Since `edit_place` has both GET and POST methods do you really want to populate the form in both cases from the `api.get_place()` function, possibly overwriting the data from the request?

Anyway you might try something like the following:

```
class PlaceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField()
    address = FormField(AddressForm)
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.address, self.name = # some code to populate with data from kwargs
```